# Is a subsidiary partnership (i.e. where a General Partner (GP) owned 96% of the stock) also considered "wholly-owned" (i.e. by the GP)

Tags: united-states, tax-law, ownership, partnership

I get how, according to US partnership constructive ownership attribution rules, a partner that has less than 5% of the partnership stock isn't treated as an owner. However does this also mean that a partnership will be considered "indirectly wholly-owned" by the other partner who has more than 95% stock, or would that partner actually have to own all of the stock directly for the partnership to be treated as "wholly-owned" (even though that's not quite possible).

This is in the USA

Comment: Laws vary around the world, so which jurisdiction (country, province, state, principality etc) are you in? Also, what's a GP?

Comment: USA, FLP is Virginia LLC is Utah. GP = General Partner

Comment: It sounds as if you are referring to an analysis under U.S. federal income tax laws and I have tagged the question accordingly.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `according to US partnership constructive ownership attribution rules, a partner that has less than 5% of the partnership stock isn't treated as an owner.`?

Comment: Not so much that but instead that a [link](https://www.law.cornell.edu/definitions/uscode.php?width=840&height=800&iframe=true&def_id=15-USC-9224646-30509880&term_occur=3&term_src=title:15:chapter:2D:subchapter:I:section:80a%E2%80%933) 'wholly owned subsidiary' only has to have 95% of the shares. It's in the definitions section of 15 USC 80a.

Comment: Your question is tagged `tax law` - so 15 USC isn't really relevant here (the tax code is in 26  USC, btw). What is it exactly you are trying to figure out?

Comment: I didn't tag it as tax law, one of the commenters did. I'm asking about 15 USC because I'm trying to figure out if an LP where the GP owns over 95% of the stock is considered "wholly owned" under securities law or even indirectly owned under constructive ownership guidelines (while "wholly owned" will typically refer to a subsidiary whose stock is 100% owned by a parent entity.

Comment: I see. Then I would suggest you edit your question, remove the tax tag and replace it with the `securities` tag and, more importantly, explain (in the question, not a comment) what **specific** aspect of the securities laws you are trying to address, as it's possible (likely even) that a certain constructive ownership rule, for example, applies for purposes of one section of the law, but not for another, etc.